# How to provide redirect URL for OAuth2 in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api

I use the oauth2-extension to be able to access google-data from within a chrome-extension
http://smus.com/oauth2-chrome-extensions/

I modified the manifest.json, entered the data in the JS and try to authenticate but get a error-response:

> redirect_uri_mismatch [...]
>   redirect_uri=http://www.google.com/robots.txt

I would love to add that url to the allowed redirect-urls but there is no such option when using a "native application" or "chrome application" I just cannot add Redirect URIs on the dev console in Google.

Any way to get around this?

Part of my manifest.Json:

```
"permissions": [
        "http://ajax.googleapis.com/",
        "storage",
        "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
    ],
    "content_scripts":
            [{
                    "matches": ["https://plus.google.com/*"],
                    "js": [
                        "setup/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js",                        
                        "date.js"]
                },
                {
                    "matches": ["http://www.google.com/robots.txt*"],
                    "js": ["oauth2/oauth2_inject.js"],
                    "run_at": "document_start"
                }],
```

My JS-code:

```
var googleAuth = new OAuth2('google', {
  client_id: 'WHATEVER.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  client_secret: 'HIDDEN',
  api_scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks'
});


function GetAuth()
{
    googleAuth.authorize(function() {
        alert('yippee ki yay!');
    });
}
```

(of course "HIDDEN" and "WHATEVER" contain the valid values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an oauth example in the google extension samples that works fine, ive used it. But you should really migrate to chrome identity which does it all for you.

Comment: I can't believe how easy it works with chrome identity... :) Thanks pal.

Comment: Just watch out that the user needs to be logged into chrome while the older method does not.

Comment: "does not work" is not something that s.o. can help. specifics?

Comment: chrome identity requireds you to be signed in to chrome with your google account which isn't really suitable a lot of the time

Answer (score 1):

I had the same proble with, oauth2-extensions! I tried editing the adapter files adapters/google.js , as follows

```
 redirectURL: function(config) {
    return 'your-redirect-url'; // here default redirect URL is http://www.google.com/robots.txt
  }
```

This worked for me, however I am not sure, if there are any issues with this API modification, since in the [documentation](http://smus.com/oauth2-chrome-extensions/) for oauth2-extensions nothing of this sort is mentioned.

Also, [`chrome.identity`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity) is the easiest option for this task!